# Adding directory to a path variable (like $PATH) just once in bash?

Tags: bash, path

How can I add in bash a test checking if a given directory (say `/usr/local/bin`) is already in a variable, say `$PATH`, before actually doing it?

Context: I am creating a [script](https://github.com/NeuralEnsemble/MotionClouds/blob/master/install_dependencies/install_dependencies_macosx.sh) for a [package I maintain](https://github.com/NeuralEnsemble/MotionClouds) for which I wish to include all steps to install dependencies. This involves changing the `$PATH` variable, but my question is more general (changes involve also `$PYTHONPATH` for instance). However, I wish also to not mingle with the existing variables and to not prepend it if it already exists.

Comment: if you look at the answers for the possible duplicate, you will see that these are quite different (detecting versus adding once). looks quite unproductive with respect to the community to downvote the question just for that.

Comment: Your question is about detecting, not about adding. I marked your question as duplicate, but didn't downvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `grep` you can test

```
echo "$PATH" | grep -o '/usr/local/bin'
```

**Example:**

```
var=$(echo $PATH | grep -o  '/usr/local/bin')
if [ -n "$var" ] ; then
    echo 'already Existe' 
else
    echo 'Not exists' 
fi
```

**Output:**

```
already Existe
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. it perfectly fits to my need !

Comment: ah the joy of coming back to an answer to a question asked nine years ago!

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this:

```
export p='/usr/local/bin'
(IFS=: a=("$PATH"); printf "%s\n" "${a[@]}"|grep -xq "$p") && echo "exists" || echo "nope"
exists

export p='/usr/local/bin123'
(IFS=: a=("$PATH"); printf "%s\n" "${a[@]}"|grep -xq "$p") && echo "exists" || echo "nope"
nope
```

grep options used:

- `-x` -> exact match
- `-q` -> quiet, just returns exit status